# Geocoder locale language always return english

Tags: android, geolocation, locale, android-location

I try get city according to current location with specific language i do that before like below and all work good but in my new project its not work!

```
 Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), new Locale("ja"));
                        List<Address> addresses = null;
                        try {
                            addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                            if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                                Log.d("CITY",addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                                city.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());

                            } else {
                                // do your stuff
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

dos not matter which language be set always name of city return with English language!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after some research i understand must set `geo.getFromLocation maxResults > 1` cause always first address returned in list , return with English language but the next items will be your specific language , so just need change

`addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);`

to

`addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 2);`
and getLocality like this `addresses.get(1).getLocality()`

Comment: Somehow this works